# A minor tweak to the populist badge

Tags: discussion, populist-badge

The populist badge is awarded to the highest scoring answer with at least 23 if it's not the accepted answer and the latter has at least 11. **It can be awarded more than once on the same question thread**:

Consider [Initialize all the elements of an array to same number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600498/initialize-all-the-elements-of-an-array-to-same-number/46600538#46600538)

I am one of the two close scoring answers (in my opinion the inferior one).

The better answer was awarded the reversal badge. I like to think I helped here since I had sportingly upvoted that answer - it came some time after mine and needed a leg-up.

When they were awarded the badge, the answer was scored one more than mine. So I was able to convert my upvote to a downvote, to put me in the lead! **To me, that doesn't seem cricket**. Having received the confirmation that this works (i.e. I now have another badge), I have since reversed out those shenanigans.

To that end, despite the scenario being a rare one, might it be an idea to recalibrate the award of the populist badge so as not to include the voting activity of the potential beneficiary?

Further reference: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)

@Mods, feel free to revoke my badge. To reach this point I have abused the voting system. Do feel free to issue a suspension - in some ways my behaviour is reprehensible even if I was testing the badge award.

Comment: You'd need a CM to revoke a badge actually, and its rare. Strategic voting is a *terrible* thing but, its a thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: It is indeed, but the suggestion I make would obviate it. But in the end, we are building a Q & A site, and these small things ought not matter.